# Flutter Drawer gets closed automatically outside of it's click

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, drawer

I want to prevent my end drawer to be closed after clicking outside of it, I open my endDrawer with this line `scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer` so when I accidentally click outside of this drawer where you see gray  `drawerScrimColor` it gets closed automatically as per its natural behavior, I do not want to do that what I see is only  `endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false` but this prevents my drawer not to be opened with `DragGesture` but my problem is different I do not want my drawer be closed automatically upon clicking outside of it please help me out your help will be appreciated thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456649/flutter-prevent-drawer-closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the exact same scenario in my app in which I wanted to disable the drawer closing when the outer translucent scrim is clicked.

This is the solution I used (still use):

```
return Scaffold(
  ...,
  drawer: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child:
              Row(children: const [SizedBox(width: 304, child: DrawerMenu())])),
  ...
);
```

The color of the `Container` has to be set to something, else it won't work. It is set to transparent as the Scaffold's default translucent `scrimColor` is enough.

The width is set to `304` as this is the default width of the `Drawer` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/09276bea258737e11b109e227f70eac94a4e1691/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/drawer.dart#L41).

The `Row` used here, is not over-engineering, it is used to prevent the child widget expanding to the screen width which is the default behavior of Scaffold's Drawer.

I use this instead of other solutions based on overriding the Gestures as it's simple and it doesn't affect Scrolling in/Dragging the Drawer.